# How do i run multiple if statements within a single cell

Tags: excel-formula

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet which can be used to calculate hours; however, I want a cell to subtract 0.5 if the hours are greater then 4. Any ideas on how I can do this as I already have an if statement within the cell.

```
=(IF(AI14>AK14,AK14+1-AI14,AK14-AI14))*24,IF(AI15>4,-0.5,+0)
```

I keep getting an error message saying theirs a problem with my formula but cannot figure it out. Thanks in Advance

Comment: very similar to this one on Super user: https://superuser.com/questions/1420965/creating-an-if-then-in-excel-for-time/1421000#1421000

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the second if inside the parenthesis of the first if, something like this :

```
IF( condition1, value_if_true1, IF( condition2, value_if_true2, value_if_false2 ))
```

This would be equivalent to the following IF THEN ELSE statement:

```
IF condition1 THEN
   value_if_true1
ELSEIF condition2 THEN
   value_if_true2
ELSE
   value_if_false2
END IF
```

link: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if_nested.php